# Writing scripts for pyethapp

Tags: python, pyethereum, pyethapp

Is it possible to use pyethapp as a python script interpreter so that [account management operations](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Account-Management) and [transactions](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/The_Console) may be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the accounts side of you question, the [test_add_account](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/blob/5e410243a8eac263c50060e0af67baf1a857ea32/pyethapp/tests/test_account_service.py#L62-L71) method should give you a good overview of a possible implementation in your script.

for the transactions, the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/The_Console#creating-transactions) about creating transactions explains it well, you use the eth object like this :

```
tx = eth.transact('d63b635a458b99f7e900477e2d261d5d13e45d59', value=100)
```

Now you can also look at the [call](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/blob/0ee25a61139af558573b9208f12d9361ab7d979e/pyethapp/rpc_client.py#L144) method and [send_transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/blob/0ee25a61139af558573b9208f12d9361ab7d979e/pyethapp/rpc_client.py#L171) methods of their rpc client implementation, should you not want to use the console

Comment: But is it possible to "stay away" from pyethapp in a sense that I define my own custom python code that is to be run over pyethapp. I've read that you can create a user service by placing a python file in ~/.config/pyethapp/contrib directory that gets run once pyethapp is run. Also, I have no ether so I am currently using a custom private block chain. +1 btw